# How do I place a footer at the bottom of my site when using grid?

Tags: html, css, footer, css-grid

I'm making a site and using a grid for my body. Now I'm trying to make a footer for my site but my footer is getting placed right of my main body.

I think the problem might be something with my container though I'm not really sure...

```
.container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 50% auto;
height: auto;
align-self: center;
margin: 0 65px;
height: 90% auto;
```

}

I really wouldn't know how to fix this. Can somebody please help me?

This is my HTML & CSS:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100% auto;
  grid-template-rows: 90% auto;
  background-color: rgb(27, 27, 27);
  color: white;
}

.bg,
.bg2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.bg {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(66% 67%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(66% 67%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #053970;
}

.bg2 {
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: #004288;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(49% 67%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(49% 67%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% auto;
  height: auto;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0 65px;
  height: 90% auto;
}

a {
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

ul a li {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotateY(-30deg) rotateX(15deg);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  width: 500px;
}

ul a:nth-child(1) li {
  background: #a9cfe2;
  top: -105px;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul a:nth-child(2) li {
  background: #85b890;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
}

ul a:nth-child(3) li {
  background: #cca6a6;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 105px;
}

ul a li:hover {
  transform: rotateY(-22deg) rotateX(7deg) scale(1.05);
  transition: transform .45s ease-out;
  z-index: 3;
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
}

footer {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: initial;
  float: bottom;
}

img {
  margin-top: 5;
  width: 70px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0;
}

#left>p {
  color: #aaa;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

#right {
  margin-left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Index</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles/main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="bg2"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="left">
      <h1>Supercool Website</h1>
      <h2>Supercool website for cool kids only</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ac quam augue. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus at vestibulum nunc. Phasellus suscipit elit odio, feugiat varius quam hendrerit sed. Mauris fringilla blandit maximus. Cras magna metus,
        imperdiet congue convallis eu, finibus eget urna. In ac porttitor diam, sit amet sagittis tellus. Nullam consequat luctus ornare. Nulla vitae lectus vitae nisi dapibus ultricies. Aenean tempus nisl sit amet augue luctus pulvinar. Phasellus scelerisque
        aliquet lorem.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <ul>
        <a href="#">
          <li>
            <img src="img/img1.png">
            <span>
                            <strong>Option 1</strong>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </span>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>
            <img src="img/img2.png">
            <span>
                            <strong>Option 2</strong>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </span>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>
            <img src="img/img3.png">
            <span>
                            <strong>Over Ons</strong>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </span>
          </li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML does not have a footer tag to see your problem. Also please remove unneded code and style. You have weird values like `bottom` for the `float` property on the footer which doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Your Forgetting

grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;?

Check Out This Article Maybe It Might Help.

https://dev.to/niorad/keeping-the-footer-at-the-bottom-with-css-grid-15mf